# Microsoft Flow - How to run an activity "When a record is created", until manually stop/more than 30 days

Tags: powerapps

I am creating a Microsoft Flow, and I am connecting to Common Data Service and getting records from an entity. For that I added "When a record is created" action and configured to monitor the database. But the step is running only 60 sec (1min) all the time even I change the Timeout duration. I wish to run this flow for long time infinitely. If infinite not possible at least one month.

Can you please let me know how to increase the duration the "When a record is created" action to look a CDS.

Many Thanks, Thirumalai M

Answer (score 0):

The "When a record is created" trigger in Microsoft runs everytime a new record is added to the database and based on how much information is in the record and the further actions after that trigger occurs will change how long the actions take to complete.

So you're attempting to have the flow "continue to run" but the flow is always checking for the "When a record is created" action and will run all actions you've added to that flow's trigger "forever".